# How to enable scrolling on Dialog Based MFC app?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, scroll, mfc

I am sorry for this question but I am beginner in MFC. I have empty **MFC Dialog Based Application**.

I am loading image in the app, and if the image is bigger than the dialog, the scroll is not enabled. This is my `displayImage()` method where `m_img` is `CImage`:

```
void CTestAppDlg::displayImage(CString path)
{
    m_img.Load(path.GetBuffer());

    CRect rectWindow;
    GetClientRect(&rectWindow);

    m_rcImg.left = rectWindow.left;
    m_rcImg.right = rectWindow.left + m_img.GetWidth();
    m_rcImg.top = rectWindow.top;
    m_rcImg.bottom = rectWindow.top + m_img.GetHeight();

    CDC* pDC = GetDC();
    m_img.StretchBlt(pDC->GetSafeHdc(), 0, m_toolbar.GetRowHeight() + 1, m_rcImg.Width(), m_rcImg.Height(), 0, 0, m_img.GetWidth(), m_img.GetHeight(), SRCCOPY);
}
```

I have tried solving the problem in this way:

1. Enabling scroll through the dialog:

[image]

With this try, the scroll bars are displayed but the image still can not be scrolled.

2. I have find other solution from this [link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10902/Add-Scrolling-to-a-CWnd-or-CDialog-using-a-C-Helpe) with implementing `ScrollHelper` class. I attached the scroll helper to the dialog with calling this in the dialog constructor:

   `m_scrollHelper->AttachWnd(this);`

but the result is that I can scroll through the Dialog Window and image is still not scrolled. I can not attach it to CImage because it can be attached to CWnd or CDialog-derived class.

Any suggestions or hints are welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Create a control over the dialog and display the image from the control.

Comment: @seccpur thnak you for comment, i was thinking something in that way, for example to create CWnd component inside my dialog and attach picture to it, and then apply scroll helper to that CWnd .

Comment: @seccpur can you please if you have time post example of hwo to create other control over the dialog and attach the scroll helper to t?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use picture controls and scroll to combination to meet your needs.

The following is a project about `Displaying Bitmap with Scrolling`. It is an article showing how to display a picture within a dialog, and add scrollbars where needed to view the whole image. You could refer to it.

Place a Picture control in your dialog. Adjust its size as you wish. Remember, you are going to display the bitmap in this control. Big bitmaps will confine to the entire area of this control with a vertical scroll bar on Right side ( the scroll bar will be displayed if the height of the image is greater than the height of this control) and a horizontal scroll bar at the bottom of this control (the scrollbar will be displayed if the width of the image is greater than the width of this control). Small bitmaps will be displayed at the centre of this control without scrollbars, with equal clearance to the left & right, and top & bottom with respect to the control. So place your control with an artistic touch to give your dialog a nice appearance.

Take the properties of the picture control. Change its ID to IDC_STATIC1 and Type as Frame and Colour as Gray. Also uncheck the Visible check button so that the tick mark is removed from it.

Using Class Wizard, create a control variable of type CStatic for IDC_STATIC1. Let it be m_st1.

In your dialog's header file (say MyDlg.h), add the following code:

```
public:
    CRect rectStaticClient;
    int sourcex, sourcey,offsetx,offsety;
protected:
    CDC m_dcMem;            // Compatible Memory DC for dialog
    HBITMAP m_hBmpOld;    // Handle of old bitmap to save
    HBITMAP m_hBmpNew;    // Handle of new bitmap from file
       BITMAP m_bmInfo;        // Bitmap Information structure
```

In your dialog's implementation file (say MyDlg.cpp), add the following code:

```
BOOL CMyDlg::OnInitDialog()
{
    
// TODO: Add extra initialization here
    CClientDC dc(this);
     m_dcMem.CreateCompatibleDC( &dc );
return TRUE;  // return TRUE  unless you set the focus to a control
}


void MyDlg::OnPaint()
{
    if (IsIconic())
    {
        CPaintDC dc(this); // device context for painting

        SendMessage(WM_ICONERASEBKGND, (WPARAM) dc.GetSafeHdc(), 0);

        // Center icon in client rectangle
        int cxIcon = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXICON);
        int cyIcon = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYICON);
        CRect rect;
        GetClientRect(&rect);
        int x = (rect.Width() - cxIcon + 1) / 2;
        int y = (rect.Height() - cyIcon + 1) / 2;

        // Draw the icon
        dc.DrawIcon(x, y, m_hIcon);
    }
    else
    {
        //Add the following Code 
        CPaintDC dc(this);
        dc.BitBlt(offsetx,offsety,m_size.cx,m_size.cy, 
                   &m_dcMem, sourcex, sourcey,SRCCOPY);
        CDialog::OnPaint();
    }
}
```

Write the following code whenever you want to load a bitmap in to your dialog.

```
m_hBmpNew = (HBITMAP) LoadImage(
    AfxGetInstanceHandle(),   // handle to instance
    filename,  // name or identifier of the image .say"C:\\NewFolder\\1.bmp"
    IMAGE_BITMAP,        // image types
    0,     // desired width
    0,     // desired height
    LR_LOADFROMFILE); 

    if( m_hBmpNew == NULL )
    {
        AfxMessageBox("Load Image Failed");
    }
    
    // put the HBITMAP info into the CBitmap (but not the bitmap itself)
    else {
        m_st1.GetClientRect( &rectStaticClient );
        rectStaticClient.NormalizeRect();
        m_size.cx=rectStaticClient.Size().cx;
        m_size.cy=rectStaticClient.Size().cy;
        m_size.cx = rectStaticClient.Width();    // zero based
        m_size.cy = rectStaticClient.Height();    // zero based

        // Convert to screen coordinates using static as base,
        // then to DIALOG (instead of static) client coords 
        // using dialog as base
        m_st1.ClientToScreen( &rectStaticClient );
        ScreenToClient( &rectStaticClient);
        
        m_pt.x = rectStaticClient.left;
        m_pt.y = rectStaticClient.top;
        GetObject( m_hBmpNew , sizeof(BITMAP), &m_bmInfo );
        VERIFY(m_hBmpOld = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(m_dcMem, m_hBmpNew )  );
        offsetx= m_pt.x;
        offsety=m_pt.y;    
        InvalidateRect(&rectStaticClient);
```

This much code will display a bitmap directly on to the picture control during run time. Remember the scrolling capability and alignment adjustments haven't been done yet and so the image will be displayed at the top corner of the Picture control, and if its size is bigger than that of the picture control, it will be clipped to the picture control's size. If the image is smaller than the size of the picture control it will be displayed without clipping, but without centre alignment. The following section describes how scrolling capability and alignment can be achieved.

**Displaying the Bitmap at its original size using scrolling**

Add a vertical scroll bar control to your dialog and place it touching the right edge of your picture control. Make its length to that of the height of your picture control. Add a Horizontal scroll bar control to your Dialog and place it touching the bottom edge of your picture control. Make its length to that of the width of your picture control.

Using Class Wizard, create member variables of type CScrollBar for your horizontal & vertical scrollbars. Let them be

```
CScrollBar m_vbar; //For vertical Scroll Bar
CScrollBar    m_hbar; //For Horizontal Scroll Bar.
```

You need to create two SCROLLINFO structures for storing scroll bar parameters for both the vertical and horizontal Scroll Bars, so declare two SCROLLINFO Structures in your dialog's header file.

```
public:
    CRect rectStaticClient;
    int sourcex, sourcey,offsetx,offsety;
    SCROLLINFO horz,vert;
```

You only need to show the scrollbars if the size of the bitmap is greater than that of the size of your picture control. So hide the scrollbars initially by writing the following code in your dialog's OnInitDialog() function.

```
BOOL CMyDlg::OnInitDialog()
{
    // TODO: Add extra initialization here
    CClientDC dc(this);
    m_dcMem.CreateCompatibleDC( &dc );
    m_vbar.ShowWindow(false);  //Hide Vertical Scroll Bar
    m_hbar.ShowWindow(false);  //Hide Horizontal Scroll Bar
    return TRUE;  // return TRUE  unless you set the focus to a control
}
```

Four situations arise when you are loading a bitmap in to your pre-defined picture control. They are:

Case 1: Both the width and height of the loaded bitmap is greater than that of the picture control. In such situations both the horizontal and vertical scrollbars are necessary to show the entire bitmap. The bitmap is displayed using the scrolling technique. The vertical scrolling range is equal to the height of bitmap-height of the picture control. The height and width of the bitmap is obtained by the following code, which is incorporated in the code which is needed for displaying bitmaps, which is reproduced here again as:

```
m_size.cx = rectStaticClient.Width();    // zero based
m_size.cy = rectStaticClient.Height();    // zero based
GetObject( m_hBmpNew , sizeof(BITMAP), &m_bmInfo );
```

The maximum vertical scrolling range is m_bmInfo.bmHeight - m_size.cy, and the maximum horizontal scrolling range is m_bmInfo.bmWidth - m_size.cx. Make the horizontal and vertical scrollbars visible by calling

```
m_hbar.ShowWindow(true);
m_vbar.ShowWindow(true);
```

Case 2:THe width of the loaded bitmap is greater than that of the picture control and height is equal to or less than that of picture control. In such situations the horizontal scroll bar is necessary to show the entire bitmap. The bitmap is displayed using the scrolling technique. The horizontal scrolling range is given by m_bmInfo.bmWidth-m_size.cx.

In this case vertical scroll bar is not needed, but for displaying the bitmap centralised with respect to the picture control, the Bitmap should be drawn at an offset from the top corner of the picture control given by

```
offsety = m_pt.y + ((m_size.cy - m_bmInfo.bmHeight)/2);
```

Where offsety is the offsetted 'y1' co-ordinate in the (x1,y1) (x2,y2) co-ordinate system and m_pt.y is the original 'y1' co-ordinate.

A clearance of (m_size.cy - m_bmInfo.bmHeight)/2) is also produced from the bottom of the picture control. So the horizontal scrollbar should be shifted up by an amount (m_size.cy - m_bmInfo.bmHeight)/2 using the MoveWindow( ) function as explained below.

```
m_hbar.MoveWindow(offsetx,offsety+m_bmInfo.bmHeight,m_size.cx,18);
```

Make the horizontal scrollbar visible and the vertical scrollbar invisible by calling

```
m_hbar.ShowWindow(true);
m_vbar.ShowWindow(false);
```

Case 3: The height of the loaded bitmap is greater than that of the picture control and the width is equal to or less than that of picture control. In Such situations the vertical scrollbar is necessary to show the entire bitmap. The bitmap is displayed using scrolling technique. The vertical scrolling range is given by m_bmInfo.bmHeight-m_size.cy.

In this case horizontal scrollbar is not needed, But for displaying the bitmap centralised with respect to the picture control, the Bitmap should be displayed at an offset from the top corner of the picture control given by:

```
offsetx= m_pt.x + ((m_size.cx - m_bmInfo.bmWidth)/2);
```

Where offsetx is the offseted 'x1' co-ordinate in (x1,y1) (x2,y2) co-ordinate system and m_pt.x is the original 'x1' co-ordinate.

A clearance of ( (m_size.cx - m_bmInfo.bmWidth)/2) is also produced from the extreme right side of the picture control. So the vertical scroll bar should be shifted left of the right edge of picture control by an amount (m_size.cx - m_bmInfo.bmHeight)/2 using the MoveWindow( ) function as explained below.

```
m_vbar.MoveWindow(offsetx+m_bmInfo.bmWidth,offsety,18,m_size.cy);
```

Make the vertical scrollbar visible and horizontal scrollbar invisible by calling

```
m_hbar.ShowWindow(false);
m_vbar.ShowWindow(true);
```

Case 4: The height and width of the loaded bitmap is equal to or smaller than that of the picture control. In Such situations the vertical and horizontal scrollbars are not needed to show the entire Bitmap. The Bitmap is displayed centrally, as such, in the picture control. For displaying the bitmap centrally with respect to the picture control, the bitmap should be displayed at an offset from the top corner of the Picture control given by:

```
offsetx= m_pt.x + ((m_size.cx-  m_bmInfo.bmWidth)/2);
offsety= m_pt.y + ((m_size.cy - m_bmInfo.bmHeight)/2);
```

Where 'offsetx' is the offseted z co-ordinate, the 'x1' co-ordinate is in the (x1,y1) (x2,y2) co-ordinate system where m_pt.x is the original 'x1' co-ordinate and offsety is the offsetted y co-ordinate, and 'y1' co-ordinate is in the (x1,y1) (x2,y2) co-ordinate system and m_pt.y is the original 'y1' co-ordinate.

Make the vertical and horizontal scrollbars invisible by calling

```
m_hbar.ShowWindow(false);
m_vbar.ShowWindow(false);
```

Fill up the SCROLLINFO structure for horizontal scrollbar and vertical scrollbar as given below.

```
//Horizontal Scroll Info Structure
horz.cbSize = sizeof(SCROLLINFO);
horz.fMask = SIF_ALL;
horz.nMin = 0;
horz.nMax = m_bmInfo.bmWidth-m_size.cx;
horz.nPage =0;
horz.nPos = 0;
horz.nTrackPos=0;
m_hbar.SetScrollInfo(&horz);

//Vertical Scroll Info Structure
vert.cbSize = sizeof(SCROLLINFO);
vert.fMask = SIF_ALL;
vert.nMin = 0;
vert.nMax = m_bmInfo.bmHeight-m_size.cy;
vert.nPage = 0;
vert.nTrackPos=0;
m_vbar.SetScrollInfo(&vert);
```

Now display the picture by invalidating the picture control.

```
InvalidateRect(&rectStaticClient);
```

Remember, depending on the requirements of your loaded image, the positions of the scrollbars may be changed. So before displaying another bitmap in to your dialog, release the memory holding the current bitmap and reset the positions of scrollbars to their original location, i.e. to the positions where you placed them during the design of your dialog, by calling
if(m_hBmpNew != NULL )
DeleteObject(m_hBmpNew);         //Release Memory holding Bitmap

```
// Reset position of Vertical Scroll Bar
m_vbar.MoveWindow(offsetx+m_size.cx,offsety,18,m_size.cy);

// Reset position of Horizontal Scroll Bar
m_hbar.MoveWindow(offsetx,offsety+m_size.cy,m_size.cx,18);
```

Now your bitmap is ready to be displayed on the dialog with scrollbars (if needed). But still it's not able to scroll to show the remaining portions. We need to handle the WM_VSCROLL and WM_HSCROLL messages to re-draw the bitmap depending on the scroll bar positions for this.

Using Class Wizard, handle WM_VSCROLL and WM_HSCROLL messages and write the following code in their handler.

```
void CMyDlg::OnVScroll(UINT nSBCode, UINT nPos, CScrollBar* pScrollBar) 
{
    // TODO: Add your message handler code here and/or call default
    switch (nSBCode)
    {
    case SB_TOP:
        sourcey = 0;
        break;
    case SB_BOTTOM:
        sourcey = INT_MAX;
        break;
    case SB_THUMBTRACK:
        sourcey = nPos;
        break;
    }

    m_vbar.SetScrollPos(sourcey);
    InvalidateRect(&rectStaticClient);
    CDialog::OnVScroll(nSBCode, nPos, pScrollBar);
}

void CMyDlg::OnHScroll(UINT nSBCode, UINT nPos, CScrollBar* pScrollBar) 
{
    // TODO: Add your message handler code here and/or call default
    switch (nSBCode)
    {
    case SB_TOP:
        sourcex = 0;
        break;
    case SB_BOTTOM:
        sourcex = INT_MAX;
        break;
    case SB_THUMBTRACK:
        sourcex= nPos;
        break;
    }    
    m_hbar.SetScrollPos(sourcex);
    InvalidateRect(&rectStaticClient);
    CDialog::OnHScroll(nSBCode, nPos, pScrollBar);
}
```

Now you can scroll your bitmap and the remaining portions of it can be viewed by horizontal and vertical scrolling. Still there exists a problem. The screen will flicker continuously when you scroll the bitmap. Here comes another technique to tackle this problem. The finishing touch to this Project. Nothing but "Double buffer technique for flicker free drawing", which we will adopt.

**Implementing Flicker free drawing Using Double Buffering technique**

To eliminate flicker in drawing you need to draw everything on a memory DC, and then copy it to the real DC using BitBlt or StretchBlt functions. This technique is called double buffering. The drawing technique used in this article is double buffering. It is explained in the earlier sections. Secondly, you need to override the OnEraseBackground( ) event. The default implementation of this event clears the background of the control with the current value of the BackColor property. However, it is not always necessary to repaint the entire area of the control, and doing so unnecessarily can cause flickering. Bypass the OnEraseBackground( ) event while you re-paint your dialog with InvalidateRect(&rectStatcClient). This can be achieved by signalling a global variable. Declare a global variable of type BOOL, say BOOL erase, and initialise it to false. Map the WM_ERASEBKGND message and override it as

```
BOOL MyDlg::OnEraseBkgnd(CDC* pDC) 
{
    // TODO: Add your message handler code here and/or call default
    if(erase)
        return false;
    else
    return CDialog::OnEraseBkgnd(pDC);
}
```

Before you call the InvalidateRect & rectStatcClient functions, set the variable 'erase' to true. Now OnEraseBkgnd( ) is bypassed.

Reset 'erase' flag to false at the end of your OnPaint function. This will remove the bypassing of OnEraseBkgnd(pDC) event and the background will be erased when WM_ERASEBKGND is sent by other events other than InvalidateRect( &rectStaticClient ).

```
else
{
    CPaintDC dc(this);
     dc.BitBlt(offsetx,offsety,m_size.cx,m_size.cy,
                &m_dcMem, sourcex, sourcey,SRCCOPY);
    erase=false;
    CDialog::OnPaint();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for detailed explanation. I will mark this answer because it is answering the question, but I strongly recommend to avoid Dialog Based app as Vlad pointed in the other answer, and create SDI project if possible. Just Inherit from `CScrollView` and everything is taken care of. Thanks anyway.

Comment: C'mmon, dude... you just copied and pasted [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3175/Displaying-Bitmap-with-Scrolling)... Is it that difficult to mention where you got this?

Answer (score 4):

Is there a reason why you use Dialog-based app? It's very limiting...

The Document-View architecture provides CScrollView that will do everything for you.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cscrollview-class?view=msvc-160

Comment: thank you for your answer, to be honest I have choose Dialog Based app because it was simpler(for me)  than the Single Document app. But it looks like I just created bigger problems for later. I will try now with your suggestion and I will post update if it works. Thanks again.

Comment: @user123445151156 - you are welcome! In my opinion Dialog-based apps are only suited for the simplest applications (show / set some settings, for example). Over the years I saw people jumping through hoops to add a menu or a toolbar, route commands properly, etc. You get that for free from a form-based app (if you need a dialog look), or any CView-derived implementations.

Comment: @VladFeinstein Newbie here. Following your advice, I made a new SDI app. I thought if I make a dialog subclassing `CFormView`, then I could use `CScrollView`(because it's the base class), but the constructor of CFormView is `protected` so I can't do something like `CDialog dlg; dlg.DoModal();`. I can use a scroll bar in a dialog-based app using `OnHScroll`, but how can I use CScrollView with Single Document MFC app? If you think I should post a new question, I'll do it :)

Comment: @starriet Why would you subclass CFormView with a Dialog? Just use that CFormView as a dialog-based app.

Comment: @VladFeinstein Because I'm thinking to use CFormView or CScrollView as a popup window (like a typical dialog window). I want my app to show different types of things(e.g. large scrollable chart, large listbox, etc.) when I click the corresponding button. I don't want to display all things together at the same time. Could you give me any advice? Thanks.